# Vlookup referencing worksheet which is not there

Tags: excel

I have this statement in a excel file.

[image]

But the “Data Sheet” tab is not there in the excel file. Still values are populated. Is the worksheet hidden or something?

If it really exists, how do I see it?

Comment: Right click one of the sheets' tabs and use Show. Look for the sheet name there

Comment: Alt F11 to bring up the VBA Editor and look for it in the Microsoft Excel Objects in the Project Explorer window. Could be "Very Hidden". Check the properties and if found you can change it to visible.